# Mapping a class against multiple tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, mapping, cherrypy

```
# ! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# login_frontend.py

""" Python        2.7.3
    Cherrypy      3.2.2
    PostgreSQL    9.1
    psycopy2      2.4.5
    SQLAlchemy    0.7.10
"""
```

I'm having a problem joining four tables in one Python/SQLAlchemy class. I'm trying this, so I can iterate the instance of this class, instead of the named tuple, which I get from joining tables with the ORM.

Why all of this? Because I already started that way and I came too far, to just leave it. Also, it has to be possible, so I want to know how it's done.

For this project (cherrypy web-frontend) I got an already completed module with the table classes. I moved it to the bottom of this post, because maybe it isn't even necessary for you.

The following is just one example of a joined multiple tables class attempt. I picked a simple case with more than only two tables and a junction table. Here I don't write into these joined tables, but it is necessary somewhere else. That's why classes would be a nice solution to this problem.

---

### My attempt of a join class,

which is a combination of the given table classes module and the examples from these two websites:

-[Mapping a Class against Multiple Tables](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables)
-[SQLAlchemy: one classes – two tables](http://parijatmishra.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/sqlalchemy-one-classes-two-tables/)

```
class JoinUserGroupPerson (Base):

    persons = md.tables['persons']
    users = md.tables['users']
    user_groups = md.tables['user_groups']
    groups = md.tables['groups']

    user_group_person =(
        join(persons, users, persons.c.id == users.c.id).
        join(user_groups, users.c.id == user_groups.c.user_id).
        join(groups, groups.c.id == user_groups.c.group_id))

    __table__ = user_group_person

    """ I expanded the redefinition of 'id' to three tables,
        and removed this following one, since it made no difference:
        users_id = column_property(users.c.id, user_groups.c.user_id)
    """

    id = column_property(persons.c.id, users.c.id, user_groups.c.user_id)
    groups_id = column_property(groups.c.id, user_groups.c.group_id)
    groups_name = groups.c.name

    def __init__(self, group_name, login, name, email=None, phone=None):
        self.groups_name = group_name
        self.login = login
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone

    def __repr__(self):
        return(
            "<JoinUserGroupPerson('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')>" %(
            self.groups_name, self.login, self.name, self.email, self.phone))
```

---

### Different table accesses with this join class

- This is how I tried to query this class in another module:

  ```
  pg = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
      'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.
      format(user, password, server, port, data))
  Session = sessionmaker(bind=pg)
  s1 = Session()

  query = (s1.query(JoinUserGroupPerson).
      filter(JoinUserGroupPerson.login==user).
      order_by(JoinUserGroupPerson.id))

      record = {}
      for rowX in query:
          for colX in rowX.__table__.columns:
              record[column.name] = getattr(rowX,colX.name)


  """ RESULT:
  """


  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
      response.body = self.handler()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 228, in __call__
      ct.params['charset'] = self.find_acceptable_charset()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 134, in find_acceptable_charset
      if encoder(encoding):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 86, in encode_string
      for chunk in self.body:
    File "XXX.py", line YYY, in ZZZ
      record[colX.name] = getattr(rowX,colX.name)
  AttributeError: 'JoinUserGroupPerson' object has no attribute 'user_id'
  ```
- Then I checked the table attributes:

  ```
  for rowX in query:
      return (u'{}'.format(rowX.__table__.columns))


  """ RESULT:
  """


  ['persons.id',
   'persons.name',
   'persons.email',
   'persons.phone',
   'users.id',
   'users.login',
   'user_groups.user_id',
   'user_groups.group_id',
   'groups.id',
   'groups.name']
  ```
- Then I checked, if the query or my class isn't working at all, by using a counter.
  I got up to (count == 5), so the first two joined tables. But when I set the condition to (count == 6), I got the first error message again. AttributeError: 'JoinUserGroupPerson' object has no attribute 'user_id'.:

  ```
  list = []
  for rowX in query:
      for count, colX in enumerate(rowX.__table__.columns):
          list.append(getattr(rowX,colX.name))
          if count == 5:
              break
  return (u'{}'.format(list))


  """ RESULT:
  """


  [4, u'user real name', None, None, 4, u'user']


  """ which are these following six columns:
      persons[id, name, email, phone], users[id, login]
  """
  ```
- Then I checked each column:

  ```
  list = []
  for rowX in query:
      for colX in rowX.__table__.columns:
          list.append(colX)
  return (u'{}'.format(list))


  """ RESULT:
  """


  [Column(u'id', INTEGER(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(, for_update=False)),
   Column(u'name', VARCHAR(length=252), table=, nullable=False),
   Column(u'email', VARCHAR(), table=),
   Column(u'phone', VARCHAR(), table=),
   Column(u'id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey(u'persons.id'), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
   Column(u'login', VARCHAR(length=60), table=, nullable=False),
   Column(u'user_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey(u'users.id'), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
   Column(u'group_id', INTEGER(), ForeignKey(u'groups.id'), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
   Column(u'id', INTEGER(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
   Column(u'name', VARCHAR(length=60), table=, nullable=False)]
  ```
- Then I tried another two direct accesses, which got me both KeyErrors for 'id' and 'persons.id':

  ```
  for rowX in query:
      return (u'{}'.format(rowX.__table__.columns['id'].name))

  for rowX in query:
      return (u'{}'.format(rowX.__table__.columns['persons.id'].name))
  ```

---

### Conclusion

I tried a few other things, which were even more confusing. Since they didn't reveal any more information, I didn't add them. I don't see where my class is wrong.

I guess, somehow I must have set the class in a way, which would only correctly join the first two tables. But the join works at least partially, because when the 'user_groups' table was empty, I got an empty query as well.

Or maybe I did something wrong with the mapping of this 'user_groups' table. Since with the join some columns are double, they need an additional definition. And the 'user_id' is already part of the persons and users table, so I had to map it twice.

I even tried to remove the 'user_groups' table from the join, because it's in the relationships (with secondary). It got me a foreign key error message. But maybe I just did it wrong.

Admittedly, I even don't know why ...

```
rowX.__table__.columns                  # column names as table name suffix
```

... has different attribute names than ...

```
colX in rowX.__table__.columns        # column names without table names
```

---

### Extra Edits

- Another thought! Would all of this be possible with inheritance? Each class has its own mapping, but then the user_groups class may be necessary. The joins had to be between the single classes instead. The init() and repr() still had to be redefined.
- It probably has something to do with the 'user_groups' table, because I even couldn't join it with the 'groups' or 'users' table. And it always says, that the class object has no attribute 'user_id'. Maybe it's something about the many-to-many relationship.

---

### Attachment

Here is the already given SQLAlchemy module, with header, without specific information about the database, and the classes of the joined tables:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim: set fileencoding=utf-8 :

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import join
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, column_property

pg = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'postgresql://{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(user, host, port, data))

md = sqlalchemy.MetaData(pg, True)
Base = declarative_base()



""" ... following, three of the four joined tables.
    UserGroups isn't necessary, so it wasn't part of the module.
    And the other six classes shouldn't be important for this ...
"""


class Person(Base):
    __table__ = md.tables['persons']

    def __init__(self, name, email=None, phone=None):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone

    def __repr__(self):
        return(
            "<Person(%s, '%s', '%s', '%s')>" %(
            self.id, self.name, self.email, self.phone))

class Group(Base):
    __table__ = md.tables['groups']

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return("<Group(%s, '%s')>" %(self.id, self.name))

class User(Base):
    __table__ = md.tables['users']

    person = relationship('Person')
    groups = relationship(
        'Group', secondary=md.tables['user_groups'], order_by='Group.id',
        backref=backref('users', order_by='User.login'))

    def __init__(self, person, login):
        if isinstance(person, Person):
            self.person = person
        else:
            self.id = person
        self.login = login

    def __repr__(self):
        return("<User(%s, '%s')>" %(self.id, self.login))
```

Maybe the following script, which created the database, and also was already given, will prove useful here. As last part of it comes some test data - but between the columns are supposed to be tabs, no spaces. Because of that, this script also can be found as [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/Jonathan2Root/1a87d8fc9dbeb80c30ce):

```
-- file create_str.sql
-- database creation script
-- central script for creating all database objects

-- set the database name
\set strdbname logincore

\c admin

BEGIN;
\i str_roles.sql
COMMIT;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :strdbname;
CREATE DATABASE :strdbname TEMPLATE template1 OWNER str_db_owner
    ENCODING 'UTF8';
\c :strdbname

SET ROLE str_db_owner;

BEGIN;
\i str.sql
COMMIT;
RESET ROLE;





-- file str_roles.sql
-- create roles for the database

-- owner of the database objects
SELECT create_role('str_db_owner', 'NOINHERIT');

-- role for using
SELECT create_role('str_user');

-- make str_db_owner member in all relevant roles
GRANT str_user TO str_db_owner WITH ADMIN OPTION;





-- file str.sql
-- creation of database

-- prototypes
\i str_prototypes.sql

-- domain for non empty text
CREATE DOMAIN ntext AS text CHECK (VALUE<>'');

-- domain for email addresses
CREATE DOMAIN email AS varchar(252) CHECK (is_email_address(VALUE));

-- domain for phone numbers
CREATE DOMAIN phone AS varchar(60) CHECK (is_phone_number(VALUE));

-- persons
CREATE TABLE persons (
    id    serial       PRIMARY KEY,
    name  varchar(252) NOT NULL,
    email email,
    phone phone
);

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON persons TO str_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE persons_id_seq TO str_user;

CREATE TABLE groups (
    id   integer     PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

GRANT SELECT ON groups TO str_user;

-- database users
CREATE TABLE users (
    id    integer     PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES persons(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    login varchar(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

GRANT SELECT ON users TO str_user;

-- user <-> groups
CREATE TABLE user_groups (
    user_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
                              ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    group_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES groups(id)
                              ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id)
);

-- functions
\i str_functions.sql





-- file str_prototypes.sql
-- prototypes for database

-- simple check for correct email address
CREATE FUNCTION is_email_address(email varchar) RETURNS boolean
    AS $CODE$
    SELECT FALSE
    $CODE$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

-- simple check for correct phone number
CREATE FUNCTION is_phone_number(nr varchar) RETURNS boolean
    AS $CODE$
    SELECT FALSE
    $CODE$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;





-- file str_functions.sql
-- functions for database

-- simple check for correct email address
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_email_address(email varchar) RETURNS boolean
    AS $CODE$
    SELECT $1 ~ E'^[A-Za-z0-9.!#$%&\'\*\+\-/=\?\^_\`{\|}\~\.]+@[-a-z0-9\.]+$'
    $CODE$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

-- simple check for correct phone number
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_phone_number(nr varchar) RETURNS boolean
    AS $CODE$
    SELECT $1 ~ E'^[-+0-9\(\)/ ]+$'
    $CODE$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;





-- file fill_str_test.sql
-- test data for database
-- between the columns are supposed to be tabs, no spaces !!!

BEGIN;

COPY persons (id, name, email) FROM STDIN;
1   Joseph Schneider    jschneid@lab.uni.de
2   Test User   jschneid@lab.uni.de
3   Hans Dampf  \N
\.
SELECT setval('persons_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM persons));

COPY groups (id, name) FROM STDIN;
1   IT
2   SSG
\.

COPY users (id, login) FROM STDIN;
1   jschneid
2   tuser
3   dummy
\.

COPY user_groups (user_id, group_id) FROM STDIN;
1   1
2   1
3   2
\.

COMMIT;
```

---

Comment: i can make your original UserGroupJoinEverything thing work out if you link me a gist with some Table objects to build it on.

Comment: @zzzeek - I guess with gist you meant github. I'm new with this and for some reason I couldn't save my gist, maybe it's a browser or JavaScript issue. Anyway, I added the database creation script as last part of my post, and the very last part is the test data. The insert for the user_groups table is from me though. Maybe it needs a SELECT setval() too, what ever it is required for - I assume for auto_increment. I hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: @zzzeek - About the test data sequence, between the columns are supposed to be tabs, no spaces !!!

Comment: @zzzeek - From here (somewhere else) Firefox displays github right and it works fine. Because of the tabs I added this gist:  https://gist.github.com/Jonathan2Root/1a87d8fc9dbeb80c30ce

Comment: Now on Google Groups as well. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/jxHXMGbgNS0

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `KeyError`: The strings that are printed in the `repr` of the `__table__.columns` object are NOT the keys, and because you have multiple `id` columns there is some name munging going on. You probably want to do `"persons_id"` rather than `"persons.id"` but I recommend printing `__table__.columns.keys()` to be sure.

Regarding the `AttributeError`: SQLAlchemy maps column names directly to attributes by default, unless you define attribute mappings yourself, which you are. The fact that you are defining the `id` attribute as a `column_property` on `persons.c.id, users.c.id, user_groups.c.user_id` means that none of those columns is being directly mapped to an attribute on the ORM class anymore, but they will still be in the `columns` collection. So you just can't use `columns` as an iterable of attribute names.

I did not reproduce all of your code/data, but I put together a simpler test case with 3 tables (including a m2m relationship) to verify these items.

Comment: Your answer seems promising. Unfortunately I don't have access to that system anymore. However, I'll install it on my home machine and test it with a copy. Until then, thank you for your time and best regards, Jonathan

Comment: Understandable. I was going through unanswered posts and actually didn't check the date initially.